# Return splitted value

Tags: java, regex, split, return-value

I'm having problems in splitting values in java. I have a string, and this must be split using the method `.split()`, but I need to return this value.

For example I have this string:

```
[#ff0000]red[#0000ff]blue
```

Now I need you to return the value FF0000 for the red, and the value 0000FF for blue.

Example:

```
String str = "[#FF0000]red[#0000FF]blue";
String[] ss = str.split("\\[\\#([0-9a-f]{6})\\]");
for (String s : ss) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

The string is split properly, but do not know how to return the hexadecimal value. Thanks to anyone to help me.

Comment: What are the outputs of your `split` call?

Comment: Why must you use `split`?

Comment: What do you mean by "*I need you to return the value FF0000 for the red, and the value 0000FF for blue.*"? Can you give us example of how you would use this code and which part you need us to help you with?

Comment: In the example the return is:

red

blue

Comment: can you go into more detail on what you want it to do?

Comment: When does the split with the regex, I need the exact value I return. In this case `ff0000` and `0000ff`. Using the `split()` method because it does not know any other

Comment: use the one ralfstx answered, its simple and it works.

Comment: "*Using the `split()` method because it does not know any other*" what does not know any other, your framework, or maybe you don't know any other method and want to use only `split` to avoid learning new things?

Comment: I have provided a simple answer for this, splitting is not the right choice here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about first split by [ and then split by ]

```
String str = "[#FF0000]red[#0000FF]blue";
        String[] ss = str.split("\\[");
        String[] sRe = Arrays.copyOfRange(ss, 1, ss.length);

        for (String s : sRe) {
            System.out.println(s.split("\\]")[0]);
            System.out.println(s.split("\\]")[1]);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can be sure about your input format, why don't you split at `#` characters and take the first six characters of every part? Something like

```
String str = "[#FF0000]red[#0000FF]blue";
String[] ss = str.split("#");
for (String s : ss) {
  if (s.length() >= 6) {
    System.out.println(s.subsstring(0, 6));
  }
}
```

That's clearly not the most elegant solution, but it's a simple way to achieve what you've asked for using the `split` method.

Comment: This is not an answer, but rather a comment.